# Using pmap in ggplot2 to automate plotting graphs of different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, pmap

I am trying to automate my bar graphs by writing a function which will take different datasets and x and y axis values.

Since the function has three arguments(dataset, x-axis and y-axis), I am using pmap() from purrr.

The function works fine when I remove the dataset argument and use map2() instead of pmap()

Here's the code I have written:

```
forest_day <- forest %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(n())%>%rename(count1 = `n()`)
forest_month <- forest %>% group_by(month) %>% summarise(n())%>%rename(count1 = `n()`)

pbar <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data = data) + aes_string(x = x, y = y) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
}

l1 <- list(forest_month, forest_month$month, forest_month$count1)
pmap(l1, pbar)
l2 <- list(forest_day, forest_day$day, forest_day$count1)
pmap(l2,pbar)
```

The error code I get when using pmap() is this:

"Element 1 of `.l` must have length 1 or 12, not 2"

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Please revise your question. Some code may be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have your data, I generate my own data sets using `mtcars` and `iris`. Using `get(data)` in your ggplot call should solve your problem. Note that you need to provide all arguments as strings. In your own example you already use `aes_string` therefore `x` and `y` should be supplied as strings. Using `get` takes a string as argument and looks for the object in your global environment.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

mtcars_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(count1 = n())
iris_Species <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(count1 = n())

pbar <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data = get(data), aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
}

l1 <- list("mtcars_cyl","cyl", "count1")
pmap(l1, pbar)
map2("cyl", "count1" )
l2 <- list("iris_Species", "Species", "count1")
pmap(l2,pbar)
```

In case you always use the same y-variable `count1`. Then you can use `map2`. Here is an example where you have two lists. One list, `ls_data`, providing the data frames to loop over and one list, `ls_x`, providing the x-argument to `ggplot2`. `count1` is then defined within the lambda function inside `map2`. Calling `map2` produced both plots at once. Alternatively `walk2` will produce the plots without printing `[[1]]` `[[2]]` to the console.

```
ls_data <- list("mtcars_cyl","iris_Species")
ls_x <- list("cyl","Species")

map2(ls_data, ls_x, ~ pbar(.x, .y, "count1"))
walk2(ls_data, ls_x, ~ pbar(.x, .y, "count1"))
```

Another way of calling map2 is to put both arguments in a named list, with the name of the data sets as list name and the x-argument as list input.

```
args <- c(mtcars_cyl = "cyl",
          iris_Species = "Species")

map2(names(args), args, ~ pbar(.x, .y, "count1"))
```

Good luck with your data.